# Dealing with string case and diacritics in python

Tags: python, string, diacritics

I'm doing some text processing, and I need all the text to be converted to lowercase, BUT the text is french and I need to maintain all the diacritics, so that "È" would get converted to "è", etc. If it helps at all, I actually don't need the final output as text, just a identifier (ex. a number) for each unique character (where "e" and "è" are different characters). Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Python version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Unicode strings:

```
>>> u"É".lower()
'é'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are converting to ascii.
If you try something like

```
word = u"HÈLLO"
print word.lower()
```

That should do it